# Apache, Passenger, Rails 3.1 - Intermittent long pauses on request

Tags: apache-2.2, ruby-on-rails, phusion-passenger

I have a 3.1.0 Rails app (rack 1.3.3) running on a CantOS 5.6 VM using Apache and Passenger 3.0.9 - all recently setup. Everything works perfectly... except for long delays on some requests occasionally. Most of the time the same requests are quick. It happens on both POST and GET requests.

For a random long delay request, the apache access_log, error_log, and rails log all respond immediately on a tail -f. But then the response in the browser is very delayed. In Chrome, the network timeline graph shows that it's 'waiting' for a long time (15 seconds). After the delay everything is displayed as normal.

The apache error_log is showing lines like this however:

```
cache: [GET /subprojects/new] miss
```

Could that be the problem? What might be the cause/fix?

I'm not sure where the problem lies so don't know what to try next. Any ideas or suggestions? Many thanks in advance. :)